# Automatically updating navbar based on section or href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple starter photography website for a friend. The website will have a navbar.

As of now, my navbar looks like this

[image: Current navbar]

In the gallery section of the website, I have three subsections, namely "Family", "Weddings" and "Friends". I am using JavaScript for an auto-scrolling feature. See the code below.

```html
<!--Script for smooth scrolling-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var scrollLink = $('.scroll');

      // Smooth scrolling
      scrollLink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 60
        }, 750 );
      });

      // Active link switching
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
        scrollLink.each(function() {
          var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top ;
          if ( sectionOffset -75 <= scrollbarLocation ) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
          }
        })
      })
    })
  </script>
```

What I would like to do is either:

a) Add a navbar dropdown that still scrolls to the Gallery link before selecting the subcategory, and then scroll to that afterwards, or

b) Make three new navbar sections appear next to the Gallery link once it is clicked. I am aware that this can all be done using JavaScript, I am just looking for some guidance.

I have already tried to add a drop-down menu but the second I add the class for scrolling, the drop-down will no longer appear. Below is all of the code for the navbar itself.

```html
 <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a id = "nameBrand" class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                          <img id="brand-image" src="images/camIcon.png" alt="camIcon">
                          Jenny G. Photography
        </a>

      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li class = "nav-item active"><a class = "nav-link scroll" href="#top">Home</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class = "nav-link scroll" href="#bio">Bio</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class = "nav-link scroll" href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class = "nav-link scroll" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
        </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="form/form.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: I would say you should go with a drop down from the Gallery to show subsections: Family, Weddings and Friends so that the users wont have to click and go inside to see the inner options. With a drop down when the user clicks gallery or hovers over it to show the drop down will be more user friendly than showing these options after going inside the gallery tab and showing those as three sub tabs then.

Comment: I would love to do that, however, when I add that the auto scrolling feature no longer works that I have implemented with jquery. That is what my question is really after.